# Replicate HTTP GET request

Tags: http, attacks

I'm trying to verify an attack called Dahua Vulnerability.
In the PCAP I've got:

```
GET /current_config/passwd HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

How can I replicate this attack to show if an attacker got any information with this attempt?

(I don't want to look in the server logs. I would like to replicate the attack.)

Comment: Although you are trying to replicate some kind of attack, your question is not actually a security question but a "how do I craft my own HTTP requests?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I replicate this attack?

There are many ways to do this.

The simplest thing to try first might be to just replicate it using "netcat." Netcat is invoked using the "nc" command on Linux (or the "ncat" command on Windows, if you have nmap for Windows installed).

For example, assuming the attacked host was [host] and attacked port was [port], at a Linux command prompt type:

```
nc [host] [port]
```

This should open up a connection to [host] on port [port]. Assuming that you connect, you can now type:

```
GET /current_config/passwd HTTP/1.1
```

And then hit Enter *once*.

And then type:

```
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And then hit enter a few times to send the http request (with the Host header). The HTTP response will appear in the terminal if there is one. Hopefully you see a 404 error and not your passwd file.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to make a script that makes the HTTP requests and check the responses, I will suggest you to have a look to the python module requests or even pycurl and choose the best suites you.